Magnetic field inside the ATLAS barrel toroid
I had understood the magnetic field outside a toroid to be zero, but the 'barrel toroid' in the ATLAS detector at CERN I think generates a magnetic field at the centre of the 'barrel' ie. outside of the surrounding toroids. Have I misunderstood the magnetic field from a barrel toroid?

Note, ATLAS includes several magnets, including a solenoid in the middle. Would you clarify what exactly are you asking about?

I am asking about the 8 toroids around the edge and whether they contribute to the magnetic field in the centre of the 'barrel'. Thanks
